# Google App external API call to box.com using oauth2, callback function not found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, box

I'm in the process of writing code that is to look for files stored in box.com under a certain user, grab certain data about those files and put the data in a Google Sheet. I have my script to the point where it authenticates at Box but on the redirect THEcallback function is not found.

What I get as an error:

> Script function not found: callback

My redirect URL in the box config is:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/{MY-GOOGLE-APP-ID}/usercallback
```

Code as follows:

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'MY-CLIENT-ID';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY-CLIENT-SECRET';

function run() {
  console.log('function run()');
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    console.log('service.hasAccess TRUE');
    var url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    console.log('service.hasAccess FALSE');
    showSidebar();
  }
}

/**
 * Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
 */
function reset() {
  var service = getService();
  service.reset();
}

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService() {
  console.log('function getService()');
  return OAuth2.createService('Box')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
      // complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('usercallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set additional headers required
      .setParam('state', ScriptApp.newStateToken().createToken());
}

/**
 * Handles the OAuth callback.
 */
function usercallback(request) {
  console.log('function usercallback()');
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    console.log('authorized TRUE');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    console.log('authorized FALSE');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied');
  }
}

function logRedirectUri() {
  var service = getService();
  Logger.log(service.getRedirectUri());
}

function showSidebar() {
  console.log('function showSidebar()');
  var service = getService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    console.log('service.hasAccess FALSE');
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
    console.log('service.hasAccess TRUE');

  // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying that the 'usercallback' function is not being invoked? Looking at https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2 , what you have done seems good. Still looking of course ;-)

Comment: Have you tested without using the side bar? You could, for testing, just copy and paste the authorization url and re-run the script, see https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Dropbox.gs

Comment: That's what it seems to me.  But this is pretty new to me so I maybe missing something.  Thanks for looking.  i'll take a look at your 2nd comment and see what I can figure out from your suggestion.

Comment: @LJH - you suggestion in the 2nd comment had the same behaviour as my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this page - https://ctrlq.org/code/20088-box-api-google-script I was able to determine what was ultimately wrong in my script.

When I removed `.setParam('state', ScriptApp.newStateToken().createToken());`
 from `function getService()` it started working and I was able to pull the data I was expecting.